How can I Create a Window with a Half-Circle Top?
What is the best way to create a non-square window as shown in the picture? Should I start with a square-shaped window and modify it, or is there a better/easier method to use from the beginning? I want to create a window with a half-circle shape at the top (not necessarily a perfect half-circle, but one that looks similar).


I want to create holes shaped that way here.

hello, maybe show what kind of 3D object you want?

Done. Hope it's clearer.

You could bevel the vertices (CtrlB then V to switch to vertex bevel):

Then CtrlX > Limited Dissolve to dissolve all these edges and rework the topology with the knife tool (K to activate, A to cut orthogonally):


There's a pretty nifty built-in addon called LoopTools. Enable it via menu Edit > Preferences > Add-ons > LoopTools

Select some squares and press i to Inset and input a value, say 0.05 and delete the faces. Then select the vertices as shown below and right click RMB > LoopTools > Curve.

Then using Mesh Edit Tools, you can further give your window a nice Edge Loop by adjusting the length of the edges:

Then with a little more modeling of details, you can come up with something like this:


Technically speaking a window is an independant object comprised of several parts, and it is inserted into an opening in a wall, it is not part of the wall. Of course it depends on your end-goal, but if you want a more architecturally sound solution, here goes.
To that effect you can use the built-in Archimesh add-on. Enable it in the preferences then go to Add > Mesh > Archimesh > Panel Window. Select the new window, go to the N panel Create subpanel, and tweak the parameters. Here's an example.

The window comes with a handy hole object you can use to poke a hole in your wall.


Very good point. I totally forgot about this addon but I did use this addon's doors and square windows, pretty cool addon.

Yup. I do prefer Archipack which has received more love over the years and is more polished UX-wise IMO but it's not shipped with Blender anymore. There is a great PRO (paid-foir) version for anyone interested in architectural modeling.
